# Android dagger 2: dependency cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

Dagger 2 dependencies:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.15"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15"
```

My `AppComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    DomainModule::class,
    DataModule::class,
    PresentationModule::class,
    ViewModelModule::class,
    RepositoriesModule::class
])
interface AppComponent {

    //reps
    fun topicsRep(): TopicsRepository
    fun countriesRep(): CountriesRepository
    fun loginRep(): LoginRepository
}
```

My `ViewModelModule` class:

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(LoginViewModel::class)
    internal abstract fun loginViewModel(viewModel: LoginViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(CountriesViewModel::class)
    internal abstract fun countriesViewModel(viewModel: CountriesViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

My `ViewModelFactory`:

```
   @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
@Singleton
class ViewModelFactory
@Inject constructor(private val viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>,
        @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>) :
        ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = viewModels[modelClass]?.get() as T
}

@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
internal annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

And for example my `CountryComponent` and `CountryModule`:

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(modules = [CountryModule::class], dependencies = [AppComponent::class])
interface CountryComponent {

   fun inject(activity: SelectCountryActivity)
}

@Module
class CountryModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideCountriesInteractor(rep: CountriesRepository)
             = SelectCountryInteractor(rep)
}
```

What i am trying to achieve - i need to inject an instance of `ViewModelFactory` to my activities and fragments. My viewmodels contains others dependensies. Also trying to separate dependencies for each screen.

After build getting error:

```
CountryComponent.java:10: error: java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at ViewModelFactory.<init>(viewModels)
ViewModelFactory is injected at SelectCountryActivity.factory
SelectCountryActivity is injected at CountryComponent.inject(activity)
```

When setting `ViewModelFactory` as `@Singleton` getting error:

```
CountryComponent scoped with @ActivityScope may not reference bindings with different scopes:
@dagger.Component(modules = {CountryModule.class}, dependencies = {AppComponent.class})
@Singleton class ViewModelFactory
AppComponent.java:6: error: AppComponent scoped with @Singleton may not reference bindings with different scopes:
@dagger.Component(modules = {DomainModule.class, DataModule.class, PresentationModule.class, ViewModelModule.class, RepositoriesModule.class})
```

Is there any reason to mark ViewModel as `Singleton` or `ActivityScope`?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding

```
fun viewModelFactory(): ViewModelFactory
```

to my `AppComponent`.
Also removed `@Singleton` from `ViewModelFactory`

Comment: Any reason to host view model factory in app component over that of activity and fragment?

Comment: @Vairavan, do you mean add ViewModelModule dependency in CountryComponent or create ViewModelComponent?

Comment: not the entire ViewModelModule just the one corresponding to the activity/fragment being handled by CountryComponent, as in why a view model factory needs to live longer than the activity using the factory?

Comment: Not sure how to do this properly

Comment: The module providing dependency for the activity/fragment could provide the factory as well. This way once the activity/fragment is done, the factory too is garbage collected.